# How can I test for time differences in PHP - from times I get from a REST API as a string in the following format?

Tags: php, date, timestamp

the format is `02.02.2018 12:00 EST` and  `02.02.2018 15:00 EST` so then I can get 3 hours. I've tried several methods but no luck

```
    $sTimeStr = strtotime('02.02.2018 12:00 EST');
    $eTimeStr = strtotime('02.02.2018 15:00 EST');
    $cur_time = strtotime( date( "m.d.Y h:i T",  time() ));
    if( $cur_time > $sTimeStr   && $cur_time < $eTimeStr ){
      //code to display
    }
```

Comment: What were the several methods that you've tried? Add them into your question

Comment: @ChrisForrence I edited and put in more info/context for the question . I would like to display some code within those 3 hours

Answer (score 0):

strtotime returns time in unix timestamp format so you can just subtract the two numbers to get the difference.

```
 $t1 = "02.02.2018 12:00 EST";
 $t2 = "02.02.2018 15:00 EST";
 $time1 = strtotime($t1);
 $time2 = strtotime($t2);
 $diff = ($time2 - $time1);
 $diff_in_hours = ($diff/60)/60;// $diff_in_hours = 3
```

Comment: Yes @Josiah Powell However, when I get the string from an API it does not work

Comment: @php_needs What is the exact string you are getting from the API?

Comment: Also, the case for  $t1 = "02.05.2018 22:00 EST";
 $t2 = "02.06.2018 00:00 EST";

Comment: remember the format you are displaying is day.month.year

Comment: If you are using a strange format [this](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) might help.

Comment: How would you do the update I added to the original question. This is starting to be a big pain

Comment: change `$cur_time = strtotime( date( "m.d.Y h:i T",  time() ));` to: `$cur_time = strtotime( date( "d.m.Y h:i T",  time() ));` if you are wanting the date to be in the same format.

Comment: What is the best way to split date and time since I now see another requirement that goes past the current date . in other words, make an arrary for date time w/o EST (02.02.2018 12:00 EST)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sysdate     = date( 'm.d.Y', time() );
$systime     = get_date_from_gmt( date( 'H:i', time() ), 'H:i' );
```

I ended up splitting date and time for better control